# How to shuffle an array without moving FALSY elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, random, shuffle

Here is my attempt; a slightly-modified Fisher-Yates algorithm.  I am not sure how to make sure it's random though.

```js
const shuffleWithoutMovingFalsies = array => {
  const newArray = [...array];
  const getRandomValue = (i, N) => ~~(Math.random() * (N - i) + i);
  newArray.forEach((elem, i, arr, j = getRandomValue(i, arr.length)) => arr[i] && arr[j] && ([arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]]));
  return newArray;
}

const array = [1, 2, null, 3, null, null, 4, 5, 6, null];

const shuffledArray = shuffleWithoutMovingFalsies(array);

console.log(shuffledArray);
```

All I did was add `arr[i] && arr[j] &&`  as a check to make sure both elements about to be swapped are NOT `falsy`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That stops it from being a fair shuffle. For example, with the array `[1, null, 2]`, `1` should have a 50% chance of staying put and a 50% chance of swapping with `2`, but instead, the split is ⅔–⅓.

As long as the auxiliary memory isn’t an issue, I’d recommend extracting the elements, shuffling them, and putting them back for simplicity:

```js
const shuffle = arr => {
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        const j = i + Math.floor(Math.random() * (arr.length - i));
        [arr[i], arr[j]] = [arr[j], arr[i]];
    }
};

const shuffleTruthy = arr => {
    const truthy = arr.filter(Boolean);
    shuffle(truthy);

    let j = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (arr[i]) {
            arr[i] = truthy[j++];
        }
    }
};
```